# AJAX response from PHP to disable a button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I've tried searching around for past 1 hour on Stack Overflow, trying different methods with no working methods, so thought its time ti make a thread.

Okay so let me try explain what I'm trying to do;

1) User inputs username into field
2) AJAX sends and checks the username against the database
3) If the username is taken, js disables the submit button
4) otherwise if its not, js allows them to submit it.

I'll show you my current code!
This my js?

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#username").blur(function () {
      var username = $(this).val();
      if (username == '') {
        $("#availability").html("");
      }
      else{
        $.ajax({
          url: "class.validation.php?username="+username
        }).done(function( data ) {
          $("#availability").html(data);
          if($.html(data) == 'success') {
                alert('blah')
            }
        });   
      } 
    });
  });
</script>
```

This is the PHP

```
     $username = $_GET['username'];

$username = strtolower($username);

$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM databasename WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();

$array = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4');

//Prints the result
if (in_array($username, $array) == 1) {
    echo "<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png'>";
    exit();
}elseif (strlen($username) < 3){
    echo 'not enough char';
    echo "<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png'>";
    exit();
}elseif (mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) == 0) {
    echo "<img src='https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/accept.png'>";
    die();
} else{
    echo "That username has been taken!";
    echo "<img src='https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png'>";
    die();
}
```

And the HTML I'm using to display the message;

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email_landing" placeholder="Enter your email address">
                        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="username_landing" placeholder="Choose your username">
                        <input type="submit" class="submit_landing" id="submit" name="submit" value="Claim">
<div id="availability"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**JavaScript**

```
$('#username').blur(function() { // typical usage
$('#username').keyup(function() { // or use THIS to check after each keystroke!
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
        $('#loginButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
        $('#availability').attr('src','https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png');
        $('#loginMessage').text('Username may not be blank!');
    } else {
        $.getJSON('class.validation.php',{username:username},function(data) {
            $('#availability').attr('src',data.icon);
            $('#loginMessage').text(data.msg);
            if (data.isValid === true) {
                $('#loginButton').removeAttr('disabled');
            } else {
                $('#loginButton').attr('disabled','disabled');
            };
        });
    }
});
```

**PHP**

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
$username = strtolower($username);
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM databasename WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();
$array = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4');
//Prints the result
if (in_array($username, $array) == 1) {
    $sback['icon'] = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png'
    $sback['isValid'] = false;
    $sback['msg'] = 'That username is already in use!';
} elseif (strlen($username) < 3){
    $sback['icon'] = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png'
    $sback['isValid'] = false;
    $sback['msg'] = 'That username is too short!';
} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) == 0) {
    $sback['icon'] = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/accept.png'
    $sback['isValid'] = true;
    $sback['msg'] = 'That username is available!';
} else {
    $sback['icon'] = 'https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png'
    $sback['isValid'] = false;
    $sback['msg'] = 'There was a problem!';
}
echo json_encode($sback,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="email" name="email" class="email_landing" placeholder="Enter your email address">
<input type="text" id="username" name="username" class="username_landing" placeholder="Choose your username">
<input type="submit" class="submit_landing" id="loginButton" name="submit" value="Claim">
<div><img id="availability" /></div>
<div id="loginMessage"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your `.done()` callback:

```
.done(function( data ) {
    // Prints the response of your php script
    $('#availability').html(data); 

    // Checks wether to disable the button or not
    if(data == 'That username has been taken!' || data == 'not enough char') {
        $("#submit").attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $("#submit").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: FYI.. this will only give you a response if the AJAX call is successful. In the case where it may fail and you want a response **regardless**, use `.always()`.

Comment: Beautiful, quick response. Thank you very much! worked like a charm!

Comment: And, if you're really feeling fancy... change the `.blur()` to a `.keyup()` and it will check the username at each keystroke!

Comment: @DevlshOne sorry not too be a noob, ha what exactly do you mean and how could I go about that?

Comment: @user3556547 Just change `$('#username').blur(` to `$('#username').keyup(`

Answer (score 0):

While there is an answer that helps you with the problem, I'm going to suggest to use JSON to define error messages from PHP. In that way, you're not creating html string tags on your PHP, making it cleanest as possible since it's dealing with data (exactly what it should be doing!).

Your JS could be:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $("#username").blur(function () {
    // Adding your field as variable to ease any ID changes
    var username      = $(this).val(),
        divAvailable  = $("#availability");

    // Client-side validation
    if (username.length == 0) {
      divAvailable.html('');
    } else {
      divAvailable.html('');

      // data allows you to send your GET values
      // making URL string clean. It receives an
      // object where index are GET indexes to be
      // handled by PHP, and values are... values!
      // 
      // Datatype will tell to $.ajax callback
      // functions that anything that retuns as a
      // response from the request, is a JSON, so
      // you don't need to $.parseJSON(response).
      $.ajax({
        url: "class.validation.php",
        data: {username : username},
        dataType: 'json'
      }).done(function(data) {
        // Creating default html elements.
        var messageElement = $("<p class='validation-message'></p>"),
            imageElement   = $("<img class='validation-image' src=''>");

          // As data is a JSON, and JSON returns exactly
          // two keys, informing image and a message, you
          // only need to put them as any other string value
          // using jQuery methods.

          // Setting <p> tag html
          messageElement.html(data.message);

          // Setting <img> tag src attribute
          imageElement.attr('src', data.image);

          // Since we already cleaned the $("#availability")
          // element, it's just append both element. You  may
          // change the order as you see fit.
          divAvailable.append(messageElement);
          divAvailable.append(imageElement);

          // I knew data.valid would be useful somewhere!
          // Since valid is a boolean value and there is a
          // jQuery method that allow us to handle HTML element
          // attributes by setting them true or false, you 
          // just need to use the very same data.valid value.
          $('.submit_landing').attr('disabled', !data.valid);
        }
      });   
    } 
  });
});
```

Your PHP:

```
$username   = $_GET['username'];
$username   = strtolower($username);

// Adding a new array that will be encoded as JSON
$validation = array('message' => '', 'image' => '', 'valid' => false);

// Database stuff well done with statement.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT username FROM databasename WHERE username = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("s", $username);
$stmt->execute();
$resultSet = $stmt->get_result();

$array = array('name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name4');

//Prints the result

// To use json_encode function, we must have an array.
// In each case, you only need to change the values already
// setted.

if (in_array($username, $array) == 1) {
    $validation['message'] = "Error Message #1";
    $validation['image']   = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png";
} elseif (strlen($username) < 3){
    $validation['message'] = "not enough char";
    $validation['image']   = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png";
} elseif (mysqli_num_rows($resultSet) == 0) {
    $validation['valid']   = true;
    $validation['image']   = "https://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/accept.png";
} else {
    $validation['message'] = "That username has been taken!";
    $validation['image']   = "https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ledicons/cross.png";
}

// I even added a 'valid' key, for, whatever reason you may
// have to only validate the valid key.

// Then echo! it's not return, it's echo json_encode.
echo json_encode($validation);
```

I would even add some *constants* on PHP to hold the image urls and messages as well. In that way you could only call the constant, not needing to searching all the code where are your images urls.

Remember, Don't Repeat Yourself!

Comment: LOL.. you mean the way you repeated my answer?

Comment: We actually post it almost at the same time. BTW, I always find cool when someone else think the same way as I do :) But no, I didn't copy your answer.

Comment: I posted mine 46 minutes ago :)

Comment: Considering that I put comments and it is slightly different than yours, It is kind of... maybe almost at the same time?

Comment: Thanks for cleaning my code and making it more efficient, but which bit in this disables the submit button?

Comment: Oh god. I'm so sorry, I totally let it out. I'm editing it right now.

Comment: @FabianoAraujo Beautifully executed, I'm a newb and understood this perfectly and manages to alter it aswell. Thanks very much!