# safe way to login using jquery.ajax() + jsp

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp

trying to realize a safe login for my webpage.
im using jsp not php

login.html should look like this

```
<input type="text" id="uname" />
<input type="password" id="upass" />
<input type="sumbit" id="submit" />
```

with some js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: "login.jsp",
            type: "POST",
            data : {uname : $("#uname").val(), upass : $("upass").val()},
            success: ...
        });
    });
});
```

and the login.jsp with some jdbc sql stuff which returns 1 for a successful login and -1 if something failed.

My question is: is that a safe way to do it? and how can i safely save the login data so i dont have to login when ever i want to do something (like php sessions) without reloading the whole page?

Comment: If you change that last TYPE from `sumbit` to `submit`, it's definitely a valid way to do it. There are several questions like this all over SO, some more complex than others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25706184/ajax-response-from-php-to-disable-a-button/25706245#25706245

Comment: but this is not what i am looking for